# Why can't my program show Fibonacci series?

Tags: c++, while-loop, logic, fibonacci

My program can not show Fibonacci series but I think the code is right does anyone know why?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

  int a=0,b=1,c;
  cout << "Fibonacci number" << endl;
  cout << a << "      ";
  cout << b << "      ";
    while (c<100)
   {
     c=a+b;
     a=b;
     b=c;
   }
   cout << c << "      ";
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: `c` is never initialised.

Comment: If you want to print each term, shouldn't the print statement be where you are calculating each term?

Comment: @NeilButterworth C shouldn't has initialized

Comment: @alifarokhi no `c` needs to be initialized for `while (c<100)`

Comment: @alifarokhi Look at your code. Closely. At the very first **use** of `c` (the while-condition), What is its value, keeping in mind you've not entered the while loop even-once yet ? If you're answer is "I don't know" then you're in good company with the code, because it doesn't either.

Answer (score 1):

There are two errors in your code, as already stated in the comments by someone else.

First, you are trying to use `c` without initializing it. Remember that in C++, when declaring a built-in type without initializing it, it is 'default initialized'. In other words, if you declare a variable of built-in type inside a function (in this case the `main()` function), it's value is undefined. Thus, you can't use it to check for a condition before assigning a value to it, and this is precisely what your `while` loop does.

Second, you are only pushing into the ostream the last calculated value of `c`. In other words, you are only printing the last value of you Fibonacci sequency.
Try putting your `cout << c` statement inside your loop.

PS.: Use the `C++` version of `C` libraries whenever possible (i.e. `<cstdio>` instead of `<stdio.h>`, etc)